# FIRST OCCURRENCE: Common Language Runtime escalation on critical resource

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Recently we have this issue in active node which is part of failover cluster instance. The active node shutdown automatically and transfer all roles to the passive node. Upon checking the sql error log.

```
Error:
AppDomain 3 (XXX_XX.dbo[runtime].2) is marked for unload due to memory pressure.
AppDomain 2 (XXX.dbo[runtime].1) is marked for unload due to memory pressure.
AppDomain 3 (XXX_XX.dbo[runtime].2) unloaded
AppDomain 2 (XXX.dbo[runtime].1) unloaded.
AppDomain 5 (XXX.dbo[runtime].4) created.
```

See dump files created for more details:

```
   Current time is 16:31:17 06/19/17.                                                                               
=====================================================================                                            
       BugCheck Dump                                                                                             
=====================================================================                                            

This file is generated by Microsoft SQL Server                                                                   
version 11.0.5058.0                                                                                              
upon detection of fatal unexpected error. Please return this file,                                               
the query or program that produced the bugcheck, the database and                                                
the error log, and any other pertinent information with a Service Request.                                       


Computer type is Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-4607 v2 @ 2.60GHz.                                                      
Bios Version is HP     - 2                                                                                       
48 X64 level 8664, 2 Mhz processor (s).                                                                          
Windows NT 6.2 Build 9200 CSD .                                                                                  

Memory                               
MemoryLoad = 99%                     
Total Physical = 131037 MB           
Available Physical = 235 MB          
Total Page File = 162458 MB          
Available Page File = 23377 MB       
Total Virtual = 8388607 MB           
Available Virtual = 8115635 MB       
**Dump thread - spid = 0, EC = 0x0000001566B37F40                                                                
*                                                                                                                
* User initiated stack dump.  This is not a server exception dump.                                               
*                                                                                                                
***Stack Dump being sent to F:\MSSQL11.OHREP\MSSQL\LOG\SQLDump0010.txt                                           
* *******************************************************************************                                
*                                                                                                                
* BEGIN STACK DUMP:                                                                                              
*   06/19/17 16:31:19 spid 2320                                                                                  
*                                                                                                                
* FIRST OCCURRENCE: Common Language Runtime escalation on critical resource.                                     
*                                                                                                                
* Input Buffer 78 bytes -                                                                                        
*       ܧ     SELECT dbo.fn_Guid() AS guid                                                                       
*                                                                                                                
*                                                                                                                
*  MODULE                          BASE      END       SIZE                                                      
* sqlservr                       000007F761250000  000007F7612A9FFF  0005a000                                    
* ntdll                          000007FEA1FE0000  000007FEA219DFFF  001be000                                    
* KERNEL32                       000007FE9F6C0000  000007FE9F7F6FFF  00137000                                    
* KERNELBASE                     000007FE9F060000  000007FE9F153FFF  000f4000                                    
* ADVAPI32                       000007FEA1B40000  000007FEA1C1DFFF  000de000                                    
* MSVCR100                       000000005DD60000  000000005DE31FFF  000d2000                                    
* MSVCP100                       000000005DCC0000  000000005DD57FFF  00098000                                    
* sqlos                          000000005B130000  000000005B136FFF  00007000                                    
* NETAPI32                       000007FE9D4E0000  000007FE9D4F4FFF  00015000                                    
* pdh                            000007FE95DA0000  000007FE95DEBFFF  0004c000
```

- opends60                       000000005B040000  000000005B047FFF  00008000
- sqlmin                         000007FE72000000  000007FE73F4CFFF  01f4d000
- sqllang                        000007FE6E2B0000  000007FE70342FFF  02093000
- sqlTsEs                        000007FE79FF0000  000007FE7A876FFF  00887000
- sqldk                          000007FE76240000  000007FE766C0FFF  00481000
- msvcrt                         000007FEA0250000  000007FEA02F4FFF  000a5000
- sechost                        000007FE9FDF0000  000007FE9FE37FFF  00048000
- RPCRT4                         000007FEA1C20000  000007FEA1D64FFF  00145000
- netutils                       000007FE9DA60000  000007FE9DA6DFFF  0000e000
- srvcli                         000007FE9E950000  000007FE9E973FFF  00024000
- wkscli                         000007FE9DAC0000  000007FE9DAD4FFF  00015000
- USER32                         000007FE9F400000  000007FE9F54BFFF  0014c000
- ole32                          000007FE9F800000  000007FE9F97DFFF  0017e000
- OLEAUT32                       000007FE9FE40000  000007FE9FF02FFF  000c3000
- CRYPT32                        000007FE9F1D0000  000007FE9F3A0FFF  001d1000
- Secur32                        000007FE99DC0000  000007FE99DCAFFF  0000b000
- PSAPI                          000007FE9FDC0000  000007FE9FDC6FFF  00007000
- WS2_32                         000007FEA01F0000  000007FEA0247FFF  00058000
- USERENV                        000007FE9F1B0000  000007FE9F1CEFFF  0001f000
- AUTHZ                          000007FE9E1A0000  000007FE9E1E6FFF  00047000
- WINTRUST                       000007FE9EFD0000  000007FE9F024FFF  00055000
- WINMM                          000007FE99ED0000  000007FE99EEFFFF  00020000
- GDI32                          000007FEA04D0000  000007FEA0610FFF  00141000
- combase                        000007FE9FC10000  000007FE9FDBFFFF  001b0000
- MSASN1                         000007FE9EEE0000  000007FE9EEF5FFF  00016000
- NSI                            000007FE9F550000  000007FE9F558FFF  00009000
- profapi                        000007FE9EF00000  000007FE9EF14FFF  00015000
- WINMMBASE                      000007FE99E90000  000007FE99EC2FFF  00033000
- SSPICLI                        000007FE9EAB0000  000007FE9EADCFFF  0002d000
- cfgmgr32                       000007FE9F160000  000007FE9F1AEFFF  0004f000
- DEVOBJ                         000007FE9F030000  000007FE9F051FFF  00022000
- LOGONCLI                       000007FE9E650000  000007FE9E683FFF  00034000
- SAMCLI                         000007FE9EDE0000  000007FE9EDF5FFF  00016000
- SOPHOS~2                       00000000591F0000  0000000059228FFF  00039000
- CRYPTBASE                      000007FE9EC90000  000007FE9EC99FFF  0000a000
- bcryptPrimitives               000007FE9EC30000  000007FE9EC8BFFF  0005c000
- instapi110                     000007FE95B40000  000007FE95B4DFFF  0000e000
- CLUSAPI                        000007FE999D0000  000007FE99A2EFFF  0005f000
- cryptdll                       000007FE9E7F0000  000007FE9E803FFF  00014000
- RESUTILS                       000007FE94EE0000  000007FE94F7CFFF  0009d000
- cscapi                         000007FE95EA0000  000007FE95EB0FFF  00011000
- sqlevn70                       0000000059420000  000000005969AFFF  0027b000
- CRYPTSP                        000007FE9E7D0000  000007FE9E7E9FFF  0001a000
- rsaenh                         000007FE9E390000  000007FE9E3DAFFF  0004b000
- imagehlp                       000007FE9FDD0000  000007FE9FDE3FFF  00014000
- ncrypt                         000007FE9E8D0000  000007FE9E8F6FFF  00027000
- bcrypt                         000007FE9E900000  000007FE9E924FFF  00025000
- NTASN1                         000007FE9E890000  000007FE9E8C4FFF  00035000
- gpapi                          000007FE9E0F0000  000007FE9E10EFFF  0001f000
- ntmarta                        000007FE9E1F0000  000007FE9E21DFFF  0002e000
- VERSION                        000007FE9D0A0000  000007FE9D0A8FFF  00009000
- msv1_0                         000007FE9E5F0000  000007FE9E642FFF  00053000
- kerberos                       000007FE9E6F0000  000007FE9E7BEFFF  000cf000
- schannel                       000007FE9E420000  000007FE9E488FFF  00069000
- MSCOREE                        000007FE990D0000  000007FE9913EFFF  0006f000
- mscoreei                       000007FE99030000  000007FE990C8FFF  00099000
- security                       000007FE98F10000  000007FE98F12FFF  00003000
- clbcatq                        000007FE9FF10000  000007FE9FFA5FFF  00096000
- sqlncli11                      000000005A5B0000  000000005A902FFF  00353000
- COMCTL32                       000007FE97680000  000007FE97723FFF  000a4000
- COMDLG32                       000007FEA1910000  000007FEA19B0FFF  000a1000
- SHLWAPI                        000007FE9F3B0000  000007FE9F3FFFFF  00050000
- SHELL32                        000007FEA0620000  000007FEA1901FFF  012e2000
- SHCORE                         000007FE9D1C0000  000007FE9D254FFF  00095000
- SQLNCLIR11                     000000005A570000  000000005A5A7FFF  00038000
- DPAPI                          000007FE9DB50000  000007FE9DB57FFF  00008000
- netbios                        000007FE90300000  000007FE90309FFF  0000a000
- clr                            000007FE8CAF0000  000007FE8D45AFFF  0096b000
- MSVCR110_CLR0400               000007FE8DDB0000  000007FE8DE81FFF  000d2000
- mscorlib.ni                    000007FE89C10000  000007FE8B209FFF  015fa000
- SqlAccess                      0000000055E40000  0000000055EACFFF  0006d000
- clrjit                         000007FE85D50000  000007FE85E80FFF  00131000
- BatchParser                    000000005AB70000  000000005AB9AFFF  0002b000
- ftimport                       00000000591A0000  00000000591C4FFF  00025000
- MSFTE                          000000005B340000  000000005B6EDFFF  003ae000
- dbghelp                        000000005B6F0000  000000005B885FFF  00196000
- mswsock                        000007FE9E690000  000007FE9E6EBFFF  0005c000
- ntdsapi                        000007FE9D500000  000007FE9D523FFF  00024000
- DSPARSE                        000007FE999C0000  000007FE999CAFFF  0000b000
- DNSAPI                         000007FE9E490000  000007FE9E52BFFF  0009c000
- rasadhlp                       000007FE997D0000  000007FE997D7FFF  00008000
- IPHLPAPI                       000007FE9AFA0000  000007FE9AFC9FFF  0002a000
- WINNSI                         000007FE9AF90000  000007FE9AF99FFF  0000a000
- fwpuclnt                       000007FE9AE20000  000007FE9AE80FFF  00061000
- ncryptsslp                     000007FE997B0000  000007FE997C8FFF  00019000
- DSROLE                         000007FE9D260000  000007FE9D268FFF  00009000
- Sort00060101                   000007FE97BB0000  000007FE97BC2FFF  00013000
- Sort00001000                   000007FE914A0000  000007FE91574FFF  000d5000
- System.ni                      000007FE88F40000  000007FE89C06FFF  00cc7000
- System.Data                    000007FE797F0000  000007FE79B0DFFF  0031e000
- System.Transactions            000007FE8BAE0000  000007FE8BB28FFF  00049000
- System.Security.ni             000007FE6B8A0000  000007FE6B98CFFF  000ed000
- System.Xml.ni                  000007FE83980000  000007FE84341FFF  009c2000
- xpsqlbot                       00000029D0C10000  00000029D0C17FFF  00008000
- xpstar                         00000029D0C30000  00000029D0C9FFFF  00070000
- ATL100                         00000029D0CB0000  00000029D0CDAFFF  0002b000
- SQLSCM                         00000029D0CE0000  00000029D0CEEFFF  0000f000
- ODBC32                         000007FE95820000  000007FE958DDFFF  000be000
- xpstar                         00000029D0F50000  00000029D0F74FFF  00025000
- xplog70                        00000029D0F80000  00000029D0F93FFF  00014000
- BROWCLI                        000007FE974A0000  000007FE974B1FFF  00012000
- xplog70                        00000029D0EC0000  00000029D0EC2FFF  00003000
- COMRES                         000007FE80F40000  000007FE8107DFFF  0013e000
- XOLEHLP                        000007FE811C0000  000007FE811D4FFF  00015000
- MSDTCPRX                       000007FE912F0000  000007FE913B8FFF  000c9000
- MTXCLU                         000007FE91580000  000007FE915E4FFF  00065000
- ktmw32                         000007FE9D090000  000007FE9D099FFF  0000a000
- System                         00000029D4C10000  00000029D4F61FFF  00352000
- System.Security                00000029D3910000  00000029D3955FFF  00046000
- System.Xml                     00000029D52D0000  00000029D5563FFF  00294000
- WLDAP32                        000007FEA1F80000  000007FEA1FDDFFF  0005e000
- SAMLIB                         000007FE9A1F0000  000007FE9A20CFFF  0001d000
- sqlvdi                         0000000024DD0000  0000000024DF9FFF  0002a000
- dbghelp                        00000029CD430000  00000029CD5C5FFF  00196000
- - P1Home: 00000029E6094960:  0000000000000000  0000000000000007  0000000000C20000  0000000000000070  00000000
    0000005E  000007FEA1FE5710
- P2Home: 0000000000000042:
- P3Home: 0000000000000000:
- P4Home: 0000000000000000:
- P5Home: 0000000000D202B8:  0107000801060007  0109000A01080009  010B000C010A000B  010D000E000C000D  010F0010
  000E000F  0011001201100011
- P6Home: 000007FE6E2BCBF8:  004D515E880FC085  53870FC73B489848  40A037840F004D51  C38B30247C8B4800  90C35B5E
  38C48348  000007FE6F145F50
- ContextFlags: 000000000010004F:  0007FE763FC2C000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  000000
  0000000000  0000000000000000
- MxCsr: 0000000000001FA0:
- SegCs: 0000000000000033:
- SegDs: 000000000000002B:
- SegEs: 000000000000002B:
- SegFs: 0000000000000053:
- SegGs: 000000000000002B:
- SegSs: 000000000000002B:
- EFlags: 0000000000000202:
- Rax: 0000000000000070:
- Rcx: 000000000000005E:
- Rdx: 000007FEA1FE5710:  4100000108C48148  9090C35B5E5E415F  9090909090909090  9090909090909090  44894C20
  244C8944  5441575655531824
- Rbx: 0000000000000000:
- Rsp: 00000029E6094F10:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000001566B37F40  00000029E60951A0  00000000
  000042AC  0000000000000000
- Rbp: 00000029E6097010:  0000000000000004  00000014AC32B1A0  0000000000000000  000007FE8CB4C56E  00000029
  E60970F0  0000000000000000
- Rsi: 0000001566B37F40:  0000001566B37F40  0000001566B37020  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000015
  66B37F60  0000001566B37F60
- Rdi: 00000029E60951A0:  0000000002F130D0  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000000
  00000000  0000000000000000
- R8: 00000029E6094AF1:  3635313030303030  0030344637334236  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000000
  00000000  0000000000000000

  - R9: 0000000000000002:
  - R10: 0000000000000000:
  - R11: 0000005400000100:
  - R12: 0000000000000001:
  - R13: 0000000000000001:
  - R14: 0000000000000000:
  - R15: 00000000000005BF:
  - Rip: 000007FE9F0A7B8C:  000000C0248C8B48  FFFB9954E8CC3348  C3000000D8C48148  CCD6EB0038246483  90909090
    90909090  8D485508245C8948

    ---
  - ---
  - Short Stack Dump
    000007FE9F0A7B8C Module(KERNELBASE+0000000000047B8C)
    000007FE6F43A01E Module(sqllang+000000000118A01E)
    000007FE6F43EF13 Module(sqllang+000000000118EF13)
    000007FE6EC405F4 Module(sqllang+00000000009905F4)
    000007FE6EC701AF Module(sqllang+00000000009C01AF)
    000007FE6EC6FDA0 Module(sqllang+00000000009BFDA0)
    000007FE8CE8DE05 Module(clr+000000000039DE05)
    000007FE8CE8DC72 Module(clr+000000000039DC72)
    000007FE8CE8E2DA Module(clr+000000000039E2DA)
    000007FE8CE9A78B Module(clr+00000000003AA78B)
    000007FE8CD344D1 Module(clr+00000000002444D1)
    000007FE8CAF1AFA Module(clr+0000000000001AFA)
    000007FE8CB4C4F3 Module(clr+000000000005C4F3)
    000007FE8CB4C56E Module(clr+000000000005C56E)
    000007FE8CB4F8B7 Module(clr+000000000005F8B7)
    000007FE8CB4F892 Module(clr+000000000005F892)
    000007FE8CB4FA3C Module(clr+000000000005FA3C)
    000007FE8CB4F917 Module(clr+000000000005F917)
    000007FE8CB4F109 Module(clr+000000000005F109)
    000007FE8CB51681 Module(clr+0000000000061681)
    000007FE2DC89FCD Module(UNKNOWN+0000000000000000)
    000007FE2DD747B8 Module(UNKNOWN+0000000000000000)
    000000290000000A Module(UNKNOWN+0000000000000000)

Here is the eventlog error:

```
The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck. 
The bugcheck was: 0x0000007a (0xfffff8a019eda6c0, 0xffffffffc000026e, 0x000000097e44b8c0, 0xfffff880196d8060). 
A dump was saved in: C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP. 
Report Id: 061917-61343-01
```

Here is the function code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Guid]() 
RETURNS [uniqueidentifier] WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER 
AS EXTERNAL NAME 
[Gcs.Sys.Data.DatabaseAssembly].[UserDefinedFunctions].[NewS‌​equentialId]
```

Does anyone encountered this?

Thanks,
Joel

Comment: can you also check eventvwr log and update question

Comment: What is the source code of dbo.fn_Guid() (included in mem dump) ?

Comment: Hi TheGameiswar, Here is the eventlog error: The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck.  The bugcheck was: 0x0000007a (0xfffff8a019eda6c0, 0xffffffffc000026e, 0x000000097e44b8c0, 0xfffff880196d8060). A dump was saved in: C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP. Report Id: 061917-61343-01.

Comment: Hi Bogdan Sahlean, Here is the function code: 
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Guid]()
RETURNS [uniqueidentifier] WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
EXTERNAL NAME [Gcs.Sys.Data.DatabaseAssembly].[UserDefinedFunctions].[NewSequentialId]

Comment: @Joel please add the source code for [Gcs.Sys.Data.DatabaseAssembly].[UserDefinedFunctions].[NewS‌​equentialId]. Just wondered why you are not using the SQL Server function for returning a new sequential Guid, namely NEWSEQUENTIALID() rather than writing your own.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may have a memory bug in your CLR function `[Gcs.Sys.Data.DatabaseAssembly].[UserDefinedFunctions].[NewS‌​equentialId]`. I'm not sure why you are using a CLR function to get a new sequential GUID rather than the built in `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` SQL Server function:

Why not use:

```
SELECT NEWSEQUENTIALID() AS Guid
```